# Multiple language examples in XML Documentation

Tags: c#, vb.net, xmldocument, sandcastle

Is there a way to include examples for multiple languages (C# and Visual Basic, for example) in XML documentation?

I'm using SandCastle to build MSDN-style documentation and would like to include usage examples for a few .NET languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My examples are coded e.g. like this:

```
    /// <example>
    /// <code source="..\FormControls\FileModelEdit\Form1.cs" region="published help using openDocumentFragment" lang="cs" />
    /// </example>
```

I could presumably (although I don't) have several of these `<code>` elements, each with a different `lang` attribute value.

Comment: I was able to add multiple code elements, each with their own language attribute. Thanks!